# Why do we learn how to calculate the determinate of a matrix by hand instead of using a calculator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm self-teaching linear algebra so I'm not bound by needed to pass exams. I'm hungry for a powerful and useful understanding of the topic, particularly in its application to quantum physics. I'm well aware of how the determinate represents the scalar multiple that the area/volume/hyper-volume formed by the vectors in question will change after the matrix operator is applied. But why would it be useful to be able to compute the determinate (or inverse for that matter as well) by hand?

For example: evaluating integrals by hand I found to be somewhat useful in that the steps of integration can sometimes be useful for arriving at a better understanding of the questions the integrals are being used to solve. It has also been useful in understanding the general idea around integrals that are extremely difficult to solve or are unsolvable. And useful once again in differential equations.

Does something similar apply to determinates, inverses, and other purely hand-calculation based skills that could be done by a computer? Rather than just understanding the concepts behind what those operations represent.

Comment: Watch this:  https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers

Comment: There are a lot of short-cut tricks one can use (expand down row or column with lots of zeros, use symmetry, etc.), and I imagine that recognizing these appearing in some of your calculations could sometimes lead to certain physical insights, but I would think any such insights would already be mentioned in textbooks (having been discovered long ago). I recommend looking through the matrix and linear algebra chapters in several standard "mathematical methods for physicists and engineers" texts to get an idea of what is relevant for your specific interests and goals. **(continued)**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Of course, you'll want to know expansions for 2 x 2 and 3 x 3 determinates (recall their use as a mnemonic in various situations, such as for some of the formulas from vector calculus, e.g. [the curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Usage)), and how to expand down and across rows, but I don't see why you'd need to practice this like people used to do by necessity a few decades ago (e.g. myself in school, before computational aids, even calculators in the case of high school).

Comment: Only two Simple Examples : (1) If you given a Matrix with missing elements & you are told that the Determinant satisfies given Conditions , you would have to write out the Determinant "by-hand" , expand it & Solve it to figure out the missing elements ! (2) If you are given a Matrix where Computer has given you the Determinant , & then you make a new Matrix by adding new rows and columns containing only 0 or 1 or -1 , then you can figure out the new Determinant if you know the Computation "by-hand" !

Comment: Would you also suggest that we do not add or multiply by hand anymore because computers do this faster and better and that we should be content to know how to add and how to multiply numbers ? Thumb rule is that we should leave monster calculations to computers , but it cannot be bad to apply very simple calculations by hand to stay mentally fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you practically answered your own question in the second paragraph. We need to learn how to manually calculate determinants of matrices and their inverses so that we get a better understanding of them. That goes for figuring out how to analytically solve integrals, series, differential equations, etc. by hand. Otherwise, people wouldn't be studying math if all they were satisfied with was letting a computer do the numerical calculations for them.

People to this day are still finding out new ways to solve differential equations, integrals, series, etc. by analytical methods that even a computer can't solve. I know a lot of people nowadays use computers to do approximate calculations like engineers and physicists, and that's fine, but hand-made calculations are still valued to this day because they give us new tools for solving new problems.

By the way, I know you're a new contributor, but we're not allowed to ask questions on MSE that are opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

Calculators are great.  But, we should also know what calculators do.
The determinant calculation is easy enough to do on small matrices, and tedious on large matrices.  Nonetheless, students should do some hand calculations with smaller matrices to get a feel of what the calculation does.  Then they should have a better intuition of what the determinant actually represents.

You may find yourself in a place where you need to program your own calculator.  In that case, you definitely need to understand the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

There's an underlying algebraic system that is worth considering. For example, suppose you are working with a 3x3 (but this works for nxn,) and you want to calculate the determinant. Then you can write everything in terms of wedge products of basis elements $e_1,e_2,e_3$, which are defined as
$$
        e_1 \wedge e_2 = e_3,\;\; e_2 \wedge e_3 = e_1,\;\; e_3 \wedge e_1 = e_2 \\
         e_j\wedge e_k = -e_{k}\wedge e_j.
$$
Because of these definitions, you get $e_j\wedge e_j = -e_j\wedge e_j$, which is consistent with the definition $e_j\wedge e_j=0$. You get the determinant $|a_{j,k}|$ as the coefficient in a wedge product:
$$
(a_{11}e_1+a_{12}e_2+a_{13}e_3)\wedge(a_{21}e_1+a_{22}e_2+a_{23}e_3)\wedge(a_{31}e_1+a_{32}e_2+a_{33}e_3) \\
  = |a_{j,k}|e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3.
$$
This works for all dimensions, not just 2 or 3, though you must work with wedge products of $n$ elements when working in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Exploiting this type of algebraic structure makes it conceptually easier to program algorithms for dealing with linear systems. Cofactor expansions become natural in this context.